# Add & Subtract & Calculate

Tags: ruby

I am working through RubyMonk and I just don't understand what the calculate method is doing. Some clarification, line by line, would be appreciated. *I understand add and subtract methods*

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) {|sum, number| sum + number}
end

def subtract(*numbers)
  current_result = numbers.shift
  numbers.inject(current_result) {|current_result, number| current_result - number}
end

def calculate(*arguments)
  options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
  options[:add] = true if options.empty?
  return add(*arguments) if options[:add]
  return subtract(*arguments) if options[:subtract]
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I do not understand what is happening in the first 2 lines particularly in the calculate method...sorry i should have stated that in the initial question

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification. Will do in the future

Comment: Kozby, welcome to SO! When someone asks for for clarification, it's generally better to edit your question (look for the `edit` button) rather that try to elaborate in a comment. That's in part because some readers may not read the comments right away, particularly if there are lots of them. When you edit, just don't change the question. If you want to tell the reader it's an edit, write `Edit:..` (sic). Here all you need to do is add a third sentence to the first paragraph (e.g., "I don't understand what is happening in `calculate`"), then delete your comment.

Comment: Why in future?  Why not now? After all, many people will probably read your question in future. You are just inviting downvotes by leaving it as is.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I meant in the future when I ask another question, I will be more specific. Not "I won't edit this post until the future"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
```

This line says "If the last argument is a hash, use it for the options (and remove it from the arguments list), otherwise create an empty hash for the options."

```
options[:add] = true if options.empty?
```

This line says *"If there aren't any options at all, add an `:add => true` option".*

Comment: So if no options the calculate will default to add, correct?

Comment: Yes, or if you pass an empty hash.

Comment: You colleagues have [something to say](http://www.naturenorth.com/spring/sound/Plains_Spadefoot.mp3) about your answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland LOL :)

Comment: That's part of my job description.